# SpaCy: How Doc continues to exist and work after being deleted?

Tags: python, spacy

From the [documentation](https://spacy.io/api/doc):

> A Doc is a sequence of Token  objects. Access sentences and named
>   entities, export annotations to numpy arrays, losslessly serialize to
>   compressed binary strings. The Doc object holds an array of TokenC
>   structs. The Python-level Token and Span  objects are views of this
>   array, i.e. they don't own the data themselves.

It kind of makes sense, but I'm curious to know how this works exactly under the hood, especially since, as I show below, one can delete the `Doc` object (or at least the variable pointing to it), and it continues to work.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from sys import getsizeof

doc = nlp('King Henry VIII married six times.')
print(doc)
print(getsizeof(doc))

token = doc[0]
print(token)
print(getsizeof(token))

span = doc[:3]
del doc
span.merge() # This updates the vestigial doc despite deletion.

print(token)
print(getsizeof(token)) # Same size as before, being just a pointer.
print(token.doc) # Doc can be retrieved.
print(getsizeof(token.doc))
```

Output:

```
King Henry VIII married six times.
184
King
80
King Henry VIII
80
King Henry VIII married six times.
184
```

Given my rudimentary knowledge of Python, I'm curious to know:

1. Where and how is the `Doc` object stored in memory exactly to allow the above to work.
2. If the `token` variable can invoke this object with all of its functionalities at 80 bytes, why should the `doc` variable be more than double the size at 184?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can find the code here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/spacy/tokens . It's in Cython, so there are some extra concepts, but you might still find it useful.

The short answer is that the `Span` and `Token` objects do hold a reference to the `Doc`, and this reference keeps the `Doc` object alive even after you delete your `doc` variable. This lets you continue querying the doc.

The `doc`, however, doesn't have any references to its `Span` or `Token` objects. Those objects are strictly transient: a new `Token` instance is created afresh every time you write `doc[i]`. Have a look at the `__getitem__` implementation in `doc.pyx` to see this happening.

Early versions of spaCy did cache the `Token` objects, hoping to improve efficiency for some access patterns. However, this creates a reference cycle between the `doc` and its tokens, which messes up the reference counting. There are ways to get around this (using weak references), but the net cost makes it not worth it in the end --- better to just do the simple thing, and create a new `Token` object each time. This also helps people from writing code that *almost* works --- almost correct is often the worst type of incorrect.